# Note taking example from Solana Dev Course

Tags: solana-program, beginner

I'm confused about the general design and account handling behavior shown in the "note taking program" from Solana's Dev course (https://www.soldev.app/course/program-state-management).

The above lesson describes a simple CRUD program where "notes" can be stored in the program's accounts. My intuition says that for the Create instruction, only two accounts should be extracted (the signer, and the system program account). In the Update instruction an additional account for where the note data is stored should also be extracted.

However, the example code in the lesson looks like it is always extracting three accounts in the case of note Create. Why would a PDA for the note be passed in if the client is trying to *create* a note?

```
// Get Account iterator
let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
// Get accounts
let note_creator = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let note_pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
```

In another part of the lesson, the code shows that the `note_pda_account` is being derived from the note contents, presumably for the Create instruction. This is also confusing because the return type of `note_pda_account` is a `PubKey` and not `AccountInfo`.

```
let (note_pda_account, bump_seed) = 
  Pubkey::find_program_address(&[note_creator.key.as_ref(), id.as_bytes().as_ref(),], program_id);
```

The lesson proceeds to use the `note_pda_account` as if it were an `AccountInfo`, to call the system program and find a PDA for itself?

```
invoke_signed(
    // instruction
    &system_instruction::create_account(
        note_creator.key,
        note_pda_account.key,
        rent_lamports,
        account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
        program_id,
    ),
    // account_infos
    &[note_creator.clone(), note_pda_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
    // signers_seeds
    &[&[note_creator.key.as_ref(), note_id.as_bytes().as_ref(), &[bump_seed]]],
)?;
```

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding something in this lesson. If anyone has a reference implementation for this exercise please share.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the example code in the lesson looks like it is always extracting three accounts in the case of note Create. Why would a PDA for the note be passed in if the client is trying to create a note?

Firstly, the runtime requires that any `AccountInfo` that needs to be read-from/written-to in a program's instruction must be pre-specified and loaded accordingly.

In this case, an account is being created by making a call (a.k.a [`CPI`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs)) to the [`SystemProgram`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#system-program)(a program that can take an account and initialize it). Continuing from the point made above, the calling program is expected to also pass in whatever accounts the callee program needs to execute the instruction being called.

Hence our program needs to accept the uninitialized note-pda account, and "give it" to the SystemProgram, which requires it to do its work.

> The lesson proceeds to use the note_pda_account as if it were an AccountInfo, to call the system program and find a PDA for itself?
> The system program does not fin

This is likely a misunderstanding. The `note_pda_account` as used in the snippet refers to the `AccountInfo` gotten from the accounts iterator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I presume then that the "find_program_address" code snippet is only shown to demonstrate how a client side application would get the PDA?

Comment: Further, why does Solana require this pattern? What do I gain from having to derive where every piece of data is stored? It seems to be a leaky abstraction, like dictating to a database where to place a record on disk instead of abstracting the persistence away from the client.

Comment: @portal_narlish think of Solana PDAs as a key-value store. Or like a primary key or index in a traditional database. Ensuring every piece of data can be consistently found using a PDA allows solana to immediately, granularly find individual data items.